# await with Promise.all is not in effect

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, es6-promise

Below is my *async* function to read values from DB and logs something on console. But for some reason its not happening.

So, I create an array of promises and then keep waiting for all promises to resolve as promises will read from DB. But *await* on *Promise.all* is not pausing the execution of code and not waiting for all promises to resolve instead its passing control back to calling function. 
Is there anything I am missing here ?

```
async function readValuesFromDB(codes) {
  console.log('trying to read values from DB');
  let dbPromises = [];
  for(let code in codes) {
    let refId = 'some_random_reference_id_generated_from_codes[i]';
    dbPromises.push(MyDb.getPromise(refId)); // getPromise() returns a promise that reads from DB
  }
  console.log('waiting for all promises to resolve...');

  // waiting for all promises to finish 
  await Promise.all(dbPromises).then((allPromises) => {
    for(let i in allPromises) {
      console.log('OK..read from DB');
    }
  });
  console.log('all promises resolved');

}

console.log('calling readValuesFromDB()');
readValuesFromDB();
console.log('finished readValuesFromDB()');
```

Output from above call is:

```
trying to read values from DB
waiting for all promises to resolve...
finished readValuesFromDB
......
......
OK..read from DB
OK..read from DB
OK..read from DB
...
...
all promises resolved
```

Ideally output should be below (since I am waiting for all promises to resolve using *await* with *Promise.all*)

```
trying to read values from DB
waiting for all promises to resolve...
OK..read from DB
OK..read from DB
OK..read from DB
...
...
```

So looks like promises are getting resolved after the control is passed back to calling function and seems like *await* has no effect here.

Any help on why *await* is not in effect in this case ?

Comment: When calling `readValuesFromDB()` you are not using an `await`, so it wont wait for the function to be finished there. PS: I would not mix `async/await` and `Promise.then()` syntax.

Comment: @Sirko that means the function in which `readValuesFromDB()` is called should be `async too` ?

Comment: Either that or use `readValuesFromDB().then( () => console.log('finished readValuesFromDB()') )`.

Comment: @Sirko. You're right with the mixin await/then. It's working but too much emphatic. I've edited my answer accordingly

Comment: [Don't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572) Also, why are you still using `then` when there is `await`?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to mix `async / await` with `.then() / .catch()`. The whole point of `async / await` was for you to forget about Promises and write your code *as if it were synchronous*, so you can use a `try {} catch () {}` block.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour is normal.

`readValuesFromDB` is ran async, not `console.log('finished readValuesFromDB()');`

So console is parsing "finished" before readValuesFrom DB resolves.

You can do like this :

```js
async function readValuesFromDB(codes) {
      console.log('trying to read values from DB');
      let dbPromises = [];
      for(let code in codes) {
        let refId = 'some_random_reference_id_generated_from_codes[i]';
        dbPromises.push(MyDb.getPromise(refId)); // getPromise() returns a promise that reads from DB
      }
      console.log('waiting for all promises to resolve...');
    
      // waiting for all promises to finish 
      let allPromises = await Promise.all(dbPromises);
  for(let i in allPromises) {
    console.log('OK..read from DB');          
  }  
  console.log('all promises resolved');
      console.log('finished readValuesFromDB()');
    }
    
    console.log('calling readValuesFromDB()');
    readValuesFromDB();
```

or like this :

```js
async function readValuesFromDB(codes) {
  console.log('trying to read values from DB');
  let dbPromises = [];
  for(let code in codes) {
    let refId = 'some_random_reference_id_generated_from_codes[i]';
    dbPromises.push(MyDb.getPromise(refId)); // getPromise() returns a promise that reads from DB
  }
  console.log('waiting for all promises to resolve...');
  
  // waiting for all promises to finish 
  let allPromises = await Promise.all(dbPromises);
  for(let i in allPromises) {
    console.log('OK..read from DB');          
  }  
  console.log('all promises resolved');
  allPromises = ['a', 'b', 'c']; // Dumb values for example
  return allPromises;
}

console.log('calling readValuesFromDB()');
readValuesFromDB().then(response => {
   console.log('finished readValuesFromDB()');
   console.log(response)
});
```

Comment: But what if I want to fetch the data that is getting resolved in all promises. Will `.then` on `readValuesFromDB` work in this case. haven't tried that yet though.

Comment: You can. You simply need to return your promise.all response. I've edited second example for that

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I am still getting the same behavior... `await` on `Promise.all` doesn't result in wait for all promises to resolve and control is returned to calling function and thus the results I need after all promises are resolved are available at much later stage in the execution. Not able to understand why await on Promise.all isn't working.

Comment: That's quite weird. Are you in production ? Promise.all is resolved after all promises resolved OR at first promise rejected. Maybe your case ?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing an await here:

```
(async function() {
  console.log('calling readValuesFromDB()');
  await readValuesFromDB();
  console.log('finished readValuesFromDB()');
})();
```

Comment: **This is the correct answer.** There are *many* problems with the OP code, but *this answer* explains why `'finished readValuesFromDB'` was logged before `'all promises resolved'`. In the end, it had nothing to do with `Promise.all()` at all.

Answer (score -1):

You have to `await` the call to `readValuesFromDB`.

```
console.log('calling readValuesFromDB()');
await readValuesFromDB();
console.log('finished readValuesFromDB()');
```

Comment: that means the function in which `readValuesFromDB()` is called should be `async` too ?

Comment: It won't work. Await can only be used in async function : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43832490/is-it-possible-to-use-await-without-async-in-js

Comment: Yes, so your solution will not make any difference. I cannot use `await` for `readValuesFromDB` then.

Comment: Then you should return a Promise and use `.then`.