# QWebEngineView "Unexpected reserved word ''" when using await at top level

Tags: javascript, qt, qwebengineview

When I try to open html file wile running local server in browser, it works, but Qt complains about line in js where "await" is used. Below is a link to example that I'm trying to run.

https://github.com/tangl-services/tangl-dev/tree/main/tangl-demo-basic

I'm guessing that problem is using 'await' at top level of js file. But I import it with type attribute set to module:

```
<script type="module" src="http://localhost:8080/index.js"></script>
```

And that's how Qt output looks:

```
js: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
[13120:13124:1219/155759.050:INFO:CONSOLE(17)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word", source: http://localhost:8080/index.js (17)
```

If await isn't available, is there an alternative solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43832490/is-it-possible-to-use-await-without-async-in-js

Comment: Not familiar with QWebEngineView, but it looks like it doesn’t support ECMAScript 2022, because that’s when [top-level `await`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#top_level_await) has been introduced.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use some methods from different versions of ES and looks like at this moment Qt is still on ES11, when top-level await requires ECMAScript 2022 (Something like private fields from ES11 are available).

Thanks to [Sebastian Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4642212/sebastian-simon) for answer, leading me to that conclusion.

UPD: Installing newer version of Qt (6.4.1) fixed that problem.